# Can I use FET input capacitance to store a charge for some time?

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, fet

I am new to EE but I see that FETs such as the [FQP30N06L](http://datasheet.octopart.com/FQP30N06L-Fairchild-Semiconductor-datasheet-68820108.pdf) have an input capacitance of 800pF. Can that be used to store a charge for some time?

The goal is to push a momentary button to power on a Raspberry Pi and after about 60 seconds detect on a Pi GPIO input that the power button was pushed. And because it is solar-powered, a requirement is to minimize the current in use when the Pi is not powered. Power on events could be hours apart.

The circuit powers on a power control latch via a FET gate. This latch starts the Pi booting. The circuit also feeds voltage into the gate of another FET which would start current flowing. After the Pi is booted, I want it to read the state on the second FET to determine if the power button was pressed. (The Pi could be started via other means so I need to be able to determine what started it.)

Is this doable? Is there a better FET for the job? Is there a better way to meet the goal?

It doesn't work [on Falstad](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2045.7144713268909%201%205%2050%0AR%20176%20208%20176%20160%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20176%20208%20176%20272%200%201000000%0Ac%20176%20272%20176%20320%200%201e-10%204.99999999999998%0Ag%20176%20320%20176%20336%200%0As%20176%20272%20256%20272%200%201%20false%0Ad%20256%20272%20256%20352%201%200.805904783%0Af%20256%20352%20304%20352%200%201%200.02%0AR%20304%20336%20304%20304%200%200%2040%203.3%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20304%20416%20304%20432%200%0Aw%20256%20272%20448%20272%200%0Ad%20448%20272%20448%20320%201%200.805904783%0Ar%20448%20320%20448%20384%200%20100000%0Ag%20448%20384%20448%20416%200%0Ar%20304%20368%20304%20416%200%201000000%0Aw%20448%20320%20512%20320%200%0Ax%20510%20298%20640%20301%204%2012%20To%5Cspower%5Cslatch%5CsFET%5Csgate%0Aw%20304%20368%20368%20368%200%0Ax%20324%20352%20412%20355%204%2012%20To%5CsPi%5CsGPIO%5Csinput%0A), but I'm not sure if that's because of a limitation there; they don't have a parameter on FETs for input capacitance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRh3KP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Or you could just use a timer. Hint: 555

Comment: @ammar.cma not sure that's really great advice. component tolerances aren't that large for MOSFETs, and generally, OP doesn't need a timer. And the 555 is a power consuming monster of olde lore, so I don't really think this would be an optimum use case.

Comment: A simple CMOS flip-flop would solve the problem more directly, without having to rely on esoteric low-leakage charge storage circuitry.

Comment: @ammar.cma as Marcus noted, because it is solar-powered, a requirement is to minimize the current in use when the Pi is not powered. Power on events could be hours apart. I have edited the original post to reflect that.

Comment: @DaveTweed that's an intriguing solution. I like it. Also how about another solution: A dedicated capacitor that stores a voltage until the Pi can read it? Would just need to be big enough.

Comment: @SlowBro Marcus I missed the part where he mentions solar. However, Marcus is right. 555 is power consuming.

Comment: @ammar.cma that's because I hadn't mentioned it yet. Didn't think about it until Marcus said so. Your suggestion actually isn't terribly bad when using wall power because the 555 can be setup as a single shot, which would hold the voltage high for at least 60 seconds.

Comment: None of these circuits would consume any power when the RPi is off.

Comment: FYI I have tested @DaveTweed's solution on breadboard and it looks to be a winner. Simple and reliable. If that's the solution I go with I'll post his as the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you just forget the fet and charge a 100 nF capacitor up? It seems that M1 is bringing nothing to the party but complication. Once charged via the diode, it will hold that charge for long enough to read then, you switch the GPIO to an output and discharge it ready for next time. Why all the complexity and uncertainty of the fet?

If you are worried about the cap charging to 5 volts and hurting the lower voltage GPIO then use a charge potential divider before the diode and maybe a 1 kohm in series to the GPIO line.

Comment: That actually was my first solution, and I even soldered it up last night, complete with the voltage divider. But I measured it with the meter and only showed 110mV. (Hadn't connected it to the Pi yet.) So I thought of this instead. The concern also was discharging the cap into the GPIO. But your suggestion to use a 1k in series should work great. I just realized why my meter probably didn't show it -- likely because it isn't fast enough. It refreshes every few hundred milliseconds. Just a standard handheld meter. I'll try it on the Pi later with the 1k resistor and report my results. Thanks!

Comment: I also have an Xprotolab Plain scope that I've not figured out how to use. This would be perfect for measuring the peak and time delay of the discharge spike. Maybe I'll make it my project to figure out how to use the if I can't get anywhere connecting it to the Pi.

Comment: @SlowBro: If your voltmeter has 1MΩ input resistance it will discharge a 100nF capacitor in about 0.5s. τ=R*C=1MΩ*100nF=0.1s. The raspberry’s input leakage current will hopefully be much lower (can’t find any data). I’d still use at least 1μF.

Comment: @Michael: I thought the standard/common input resistance was 10 MΩ, not 1 MΩ(?)

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Ah, yes, apparently it is. But 1s for going down to 37% charge (and 5s for <1%) is not that much time either.

Comment: Well I hooked this all up and... nothing. GPIO won't even see it. Perhaps I need bigger caps? I'm going to attempt the CMOS flip-flop mentioned by David Tweed, as I actually have some chips on hand. Seems like it'd be more robust. Thanks!

Comment: @SlowBro: Try bigger caps and make sure you don’t have any pull-downs enabled. And of course make sure your voltage divider gives the correct voltage. It should work.

Answer (score 4):

You will need a low leakage diode to have a good chance of achieving this. Ballpark wise, assuming the 1N4148 to the gate leaks ~8nA consistently around 5V and down we can make a ballpark calculation using the capacitor equation and the parameters of the MOSFET.
$$
I(t)=C \frac{dV}{dT}
$$
If we set I=8nA, Vd=0.7 (diode drop), Vgs=2.5 we can calculate that once you remove the switch the MOSFET will be on while the gate voltage discharges from 4.3V to 2.5V or over a span of 1.8V.

Solving for dT we get dT=0.18 seconds. Not alot, so you will need to find a lower leakage diode. Even then this will be highly dependent on temperature and device variations of both the diode and the MOSFET. So dont do this if you want accuracy. But you might find something that leaves you ballpark around 60 seconds at room temperature with the correct component choices.

As someone pointed out, for this to work the design would need to be converted to ground the source and use it as a inverter.

Comment: He should include the current sinking into Pi GPIO for this calculation

Comment: It'll be outdoors so temperature swings can be a big factor. I'll take this into consideration, but I'm favoring @Andy aka's solution.

Comment: But that isn't how the OP's source-follower circuit works! The gate never charges to more than Vgs to begin with. To get the effect you're talking about, the source would have to be grounded, and the output taken from the drain terminal.

Comment: Dave Tweed is right, and i agree that Andys solution would be preferrable. The solution you had would need to be modified to ground the source, and convert it to a inverter, in order for my suggestion to work.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I use FET input capacitance to store a charge for some time?

Yes. The length of time will depend on the circuitry, the leakage, the construction, and factors that impact those conditions. You can easily try it with real parts.

Comment: Indeed, you can even test this with just a multimeter and a bare MOSFET.  Charge up the gate with the diode test mode, then test the continuity between source and drain, then discharge the gate again and test again.  Be careful not to zap the FET with ESD though.  In my experiments with this (just holding the FET in my hand and probing with the meter, you can get the gate to hold a known state for several minutes at least.  And it's a neat party trick :)

Comment: @Wossname "And it's a neat party trick" Haha